# Triggering any HTTP method request from pure HTML

Tags: html, anchor, href, http-method

I wold like to send a non-`GET` `http` request from my `HTML` web-page.

But, I don't want to use any script (`js`, `php`, etc.).

I want this request to be sent only using HTML.
Is that feasible?

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <a href="http://www.example.com/">some text</a>
    </body>
  </html>
```

If a user will click on `"some text"` it will trigger an `http` `GET` request. Now, let's say I would like to send a `POST` request, but not use any scripts, only pure `HTML` - is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an HTML [`<form>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html) element, you can specify the [`method`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method) as either `GET` or `POST`.

There is no way other way of specifying a non-`GET` request, nor any other HTTP verb apart from `GET` and `POST` in HTML.